# Extract Subthreshold Slope

Tags: mosfet

I have a number of Vg vs Id data sets/plots for a transistor under a number of different conditions that I need to extract the subthreshold slope from but I am not sure the best way to do it.  I have done some rough hand calculations subtracting a gate voltage from another over a decade of drain current change in the subthreshold region but I am looking for a more precise way of doing it.  Is there a good algorithm for calculating the subthreshold slope from a .csv file of data points?

Answer (score 1):

You plot log(ID) over VG. You see a linear region in this plot. At room temperature, the theoretical maximum slope is approx. 1 dec/60 mV. Your device might or might not be lower than this.

The slope should be pretty constant along the line.